# Android - Add a button outside LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout

**How can I add a button outside this LinearLayout?**

I need it to be on the bottom. I tried it myself in a few ways, but it adds the same button in each row! I'd appreciate some help, thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox_alarm_active"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="5dp" />
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_alarm_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_alarm_days"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note to editors: I saw other similar questions, but the problem is a bit different for me, so those don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want it to be at exact bottomview of the layout, then do this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearlayot"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_alarm_active"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_alarm_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_alarm_days"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
     </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

   <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttontoadd"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayot"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but if you want it to be at the extreme bottom view that is the parent's bottom the change the to this.. (change id="@+id/buttontoadd")

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttontoadd"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:text="Button" />
```

maintain its position..Let me know if it helps....

EDIT: change this

```
  <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearlayot"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
```

to

```
  <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearlayot"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
```

Comment: Wait, I was wrong. It shows it where it should be in Graphical Layout using Eclipse. But I get the same problem on a real device o.O

Comment: thats because the linear layout is wrap_content which wraps around its children views-(not your children views doesnt take up much space), change it and make it match_parent and it will lay perfectly on your device -(this is because match_parent lays your view to match the device size ratio) check my edit,now @AnonymousMouse